# How to send a failure notification when aws glue job is running longer than threshold time

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have scenario to implement a sns notification task when a aws glue job running longer than expected. How can I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CloudWatch Events Event Examples From AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#glue-event-types) shows an event from AWS Glue called **Timeout**:

```json
{
    "version":"0",
    "id":"abcdef00-1234-5678-9abc-def012345678",
    "detail-type":"Glue Job State Change",
    "source":"aws.glue",
    "account":"123456789012",
    "time":"2017-11-20T20:22:06Z",
    "region":"us-east-1",
    "resources":[],
    "detail":{
        "jobName":"MyJob",
        "severity":"WARN",
        "state":"TIMEOUT",
        "jobRunId":"jr_abc0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789def",
        "message":"Job run timed out"
    }
}
```

From [AWS Glue now supports Timeout Values for ETL jobs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/aws-glue-now-supports-timeout-values-for-etl-jobs/#:%7E:text=When%20the%20specified%20timeout%20limit,timeout%20value%20of%2048%20hours.):

> AWS Glue now enables you to set a timeout value on extract, transform, and load (ETL) jobs as a safeguard against runaway jobs... When the specified timeout limit has been reached, **Glue will terminate the ETL job**, stop billing for the job, and **send a job TIMEOUT notification** to Amazon CloudWatch.

However, if you merely wish to receive a Notification after a given period, rather than terminating the job, this option is *not* suitable. For that, you would need to write your own system for monitoring the duration, possibly triggered by the start of a job.

See also: [Automating AWS Glue with CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/automating-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-events.html)